# Is there a way to use polymer's elements without the use of node. Js npm and bower?

Tags: html, node.js, polymer, bower, bower-install

I want to know if it is possible to download some library from a link where from i can include the elements (polymer's) to my html file? Or somehow install Polymer without bower of npm from node.js?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You would have to manually perform the tasks of a package manager (i.e., among other things, download every dependency of each element you use into a subdirectory of your project). Why do you want to punish yourself with this task? If you wish to use the Polymer CLI (build tools, local server, linter, etc.), you would need Node4+. Technically, you could recreate those tools with a different technology, but why would you want to?

Comment: My npm just doesn't work. But other than that node does i believe. What would be your advice on how i go about this. Could you leave instructions in an answer? Also i have Git installed, if that helps. :) i would like to use polymer CLI

Comment: The thought of even listing those instructions makes my head hurt. :) This is technically an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Don't you want to fix your `npm` setup so that you could avoid manual labor? I highly recommend asking a new question to get answers to your `npm` problem.

Comment: I think it would be best to, as you say, fix my npm problem.

Comment: It looks like i hhave to do this manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41365127/1073945) by Sawan Patodia is correct but I'd like to add that for quick hacks or testing you could also use [Polygit CDN](https://polygit.org/).

**Example usage:**

```
<base href="http://polygit.org/components/">

<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
```

If interested you could also view the [Polycast by Rob Dodson about Polygit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyph_r8wUpc).

Answer (score 3):

Download the zip file of the component you want to use directly from github and add the file to bower_components folder.